# Elastic search language configuration

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, sonata-admin, foselasticabundle

I work on a project with symfony and sonata admin,
my project will be in two language: fr and de so i used elastic search so i installed "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "3.2.1".
in the elasticconfiguration file how can add the language configuration?
this is my fos elastic bundle configuration file:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: %elastic_host%, port: %elastic_port% }
    indexes:
        myproject:
            settings:
                index:
                    analysis:
                       analyzer:
                           custom_analyzer :
                               type     :    custom
                               tokenizer:    nGram
                               filter   :    [stopwords, asciifolding ,lowercase, elision, worddelimiter]
                           custom_search_analyzer :
                               type     :    custom
                               tokenizer:    standard
                               filter   :    [stopwords, asciifolding ,lowercase, elision, worddelimiter]
                       tokenizer:
                           nGram:
                               type:     nGram
                               min_gram: 3
                               max_gram: 20
                       filter:
                           elision:
                               type:     elision
                               articles: [l, m, t, qu, n, s, j, d]
                           stopwords:
                               type:      stop
                               stopwords: [_french_]
                               ignore_case : true
                           worddelimiter:
                               type:      word_delimiter

            types:
                produit:
                    mappings:
                        titre: ~
                        active:
                            type: boolean
                        descriptifTexteOriginal:
                            index_analyzer: custom_analyzer
                            search_analyzer : custom_search_analyzer
                            type: string
                            norms: { enabled: false }
                            explain: true
                            index_options: freqs

                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: myproject\BOBundle\Entity\Produit
                        finder: ~
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
```

Comment: How do you want to add your language support? For example, you can seperate your index or you can seperate your fields which  want to translate.

Comment: Please give some extra information about your data structure and your opinions?

Comment: sorry i d'ont undestend what you mean with   data structure

Comment: In my opinion, there is two type of multiple language support of elasticsearch data structures. First one is separating indexes second one is separating fields. Which one do you think to do? This solutions also handle translation situation.

Comment: I need the easiest solution or can give you any documentation or a brief explanation please !

Answer (score 0):

In base, we will about two situtaion. First one is you have a field and it can store 
two or more different language text. For example, you have a title field which can 
store english or turkish. Not both of them is at the same time. The second situation 
is, your data have multiple language value in one document.

In my opinion, there is two way of this problem, too. First is separate your fields 
and second is separating index. Let's explain both of them to you:

Think about you have the following data for your products on e-commerce website:

```
id => identify of your data
name => name of the product
price => price of the product
```

Our first opinion has multiple option. Now, let's look our first option of the first 
opinion and create a mapping:

```
PUT 44369578
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "id": { "type": "integer" },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "en": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "englishAnalyzer"
            },
            "tr": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "turkishAnalyzer"
            }
          }
        },
        "price": { "type": "double"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is a name field which can take english or turkish value
And in this field only can handle one of them. Not both of them 
When you try to improve your language support, you should change your mapping, too.

Then, let's look our second options of the first opinion.

```
PUT 44369578
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "id": { "type": "integer" },
        "name_en": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "englishAnalyzer" },
        "name_tr": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "turkishAnalyzer" },
        "price": { "type": "double"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this example there is two field for our two language. And we can 
save english and turkish values for our documents at the same time. 
When you try to improve your language support, you should change your mapping, too. 
These are two options of the first opinion.

Now, lets look our second opinion. In this example, we have same data structure for 
product documents. But we create multiple indexes for each languages.

```
PUT 44369578
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "id": { "type": "integer" },
        "name": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "englishAnalyzer" },
        "price": { "type": "double"}
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT 44369578
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "id": { "type": "integer" },
        "name": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "turkishAnalyzer" },
        "price": { "type": "double"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this opinion, we have two documents for each document and we try to merge the 
documents on our application while we are searching documents. This is odd part of 
this opinion. But we can create a new index while we create a new language support.

Conclusion, As far as, I know these three methods. You can select one of them and 
don't forget, each election will get some features but take away some features.